# Making a question using “pourquoi”

Tags: questions, interrogative

What is the correct way to ask a question using *pourquoi* and a person's name?

> Pourquoi Marie est-elle en colère ?

or

> Pourquoi est-Marie en colère ?

or

> Pourquoi Marie est en colère ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct et soutenu :

> Pourquoi Marie est-elle en colère ?

Incorrect (ne jamais l'employer) :

> Pourquoi est-Marie en colère ?

Correct, surtout à l'oral :

> Pourquoi Marie est en colère ?

Comment: Let me add a variation: *Pourquoi est-ce que Marie est en colère ?* (usually spoken).

Comment: *Pourquoi Marie est en colère* can also be used in written form with indirect speach: *J'aimerais savoir pourquoi Marie est en colère.*

Answer (score 2):

You can only make an inverted pair (like *est-il*) with a pronoun. That said, you can use such a device as a prop in a question involving nouns or proper nouns (like in your first sentence).